# Making callout from trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, callout

Need is whenever a account is created under salesforce, we need to fetch the 3rd party api which will validate the address for the account record and based upon response it will block or allow system to create the record.

Now from trigger we can make only asynchronous callout before insert operation. But the problem is trigger execution thread will be different from the asynchronous job thread from where the api callout is done. So how the trigger will know that the response is received. Any solution of this issue?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. While you have framed the problem well, there is no mention of any specific research you have done.

Comment: Fundamentally you cannot block the creation in a selective manner based on the result from a unique callout. You probably need to have a validity indicator on all Account records, only setting them valid when the external system indicates they should be, and live with the insertion creating the record as "not yet validated".

Comment: Refer to this article, this can be helpful https://medium.com/@CoachRWZ/salesforce-chaining-queueable-apex-callouts-53615b8dee92

Comment: Or is there any other structure to follow rather than trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a custom "form" to create a new Record using a Lightning Component and use it as a Standard Action override. You would then perform the API callout from Javascript (or build an @AuraEnabled Apex method to callout) before you even attempt to save the Record.

From a trigger you cannot achieve this.

Override considerations: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.links_override_considerations.htm&type=5